# How to validate web api response

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I am working on a web api where I need to validate response returned. I want to write some generic code to ensure that response returned from api is in a correct format.

Basically there are fields like status, remarks etc which should be present in response if these are null or invalid then i should return some error code but not sure how to achieve this, can someone guide me here? Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Sudama

Comment: It isn't clear how you are generating a response nor what type of response you are generating. For instance, are you generating a response from a model and formatting it as JSON?

Comment: Hi Shaun, I have written custom input/output formatter to accept/return soap+xml in asp.net core web api . I am validating the request using global filter but not sure how can achieve same thing for the output.

Comment: You could use a result filter for that. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html#result-filters

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <Body><FindResponse xmlns="http://mywebsite.com/GBPortal">
      <FindResult>
        <Remarks>Sample remark.</Remarks>
  <status>null </status>  
   </FindResult>
    </FindResponse>
  </Body>
</Envelope>

Comment: Any sample for creating custom result filter for validating response??

Comment: Why do you want to validate your response after generating it, and at runtime at that? What would such a validator look like? Do you want a validator for each response type? It sounds like you should use unit tests to verify your code outputs the correct structures during development.

Comment: @codecaster Yes i am looking for a validator for each response type. there are few fields which are mandatory to be returned to the client and in case they are missing in the response then i want to return some error code. In the current scenario if status of remarks are missing or they are null then i want to return 500 error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might work for you. It assumes you're using an `ObjectResult` though you can adapt it to the `IActionResult` implementation that you're actually using. The following is not production code; rather, it gives a sense of what you could do.

```
public class MyResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {

    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var result = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        var value = result.Value as MyCustomType;
        if (!IsValid(value) 
        {
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(500);
        }
    }

    private bool IsValid(MyCustomType value) 
    {
        return value != null && 
            value.Status != null &&
            value.Remarks != null;
    }
}
```

Comment: context has only action descriptor , HttpContext, Filter, RouteData, ModelState & Result property so not sure how to access custom properties, I am sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: @SudamaTripathi What custom properties do you want to access?

Comment: If i am checking context.result i see content types , delcared types , formtters, status code and value which has my custom POCO object any sugestion on accessing properties

Comment: I posted sample response in my previous comment. that is serialized soap message which has status , remarks and i want to access the values of these properties

Comment: @SudamaTripathi Do a cast of the `Value` to the type of your object.